# How to get all pods without jobs

Tags: list, kubernetes, filter, kubectl

Is it possible to retrieve all pods without taking jobs?

```
kubectl get pods 
pod1                                      1/1     Running     1          28d
pod2                                      1/1     Running     1          28d
pods3                                     0/1     Completed   0          30m
pod4                                      0/1     Completed   0          30m
```

I don't want to see jobs, but only the other pod.
I don't want to fetch them basing on "Running State" because I would like to verify if all deployment I am trying to install are "deployed".
Basing on that I wanted to use the following command, but it is fetching also jobs I am trying to exclude:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready pods --all --timeout=600s
```

Comment: when you do `kubectl get pods` you get the pods, you don't get the jobs. You get the jobs if you do `kubectl get jobs`. Unless for you jobs are pods that are completed, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Add a special label (e.g. `kind=pod`) to your job pods. Then use `kubectl get pods -l kind!=pod`.

Comment: I agree that this could be an option, so no other option without labeling pods with these rules.. right?

Comment: I don’t think ‘kubectl get’ has more filtering options.

Answer (score 1):

If using a bit of scripting is OK...this one-liner should return the names of all "non-Jobs" pods in all namespaces:

```
for p in `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{';'}{.metadata.ownerReferences[?(@.kind != 'Job')].name}{'\n'}{end}"`; do v_owner_name=$(echo $p | cut -d';' -f2); if [ ! -z "$v_owner_name" ]; then v_pod_name=$(echo $p | cut -d';' -f1); echo $v_pod_name; fi; done
```

Using the above as a foundation, the following aims to return all "non-Jobs" pods in `Ready` status:

```
for p in `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{';'}{'Ready='}{.status.conditions[?(@.type == 'Ready')].status}{';'}{.metadata.ownerReferences[?(@.kind != 'Job')].name}{'\n'}{end}"`; do v_owner_name=$(echo $p | cut -d';' -f3); if [ ! -z "$v_owner_name" ]; then v_pod_name=$(echo $p | cut -d';' -f1,2); echo $v_pod_name; fi; done
```

[This doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) explains (arguably - to some degree) the JSONPath support in `kubectl`.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is -

> I would like to verify if all deployment I am trying to install are
>   "deployed"

Then this is not the right way of checking Pods status in Kubernetes. Please check the **replicas** and  **readyReplicas** for your deployment.

```
kubectl get deployment <deployment-Name> -ojson | jq -r '.status | { desired: .replicas, ready: .readyReplicas }'
```

Output:-

```
{
  "desired": 1,
  "ready": 1
}
```

Here I am using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (It's very handy) utility to parse the stuff